# Setting item height of a list view? (using custom draw)

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I set the row height of a custom drawn list view? Or does it require an owner drawn list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the mode you are using it in.  <strike>In some modes, you can use the `LVM_SETITEMHEIGHT` message.</strike>  In <strike>others</strike> some modes, the item height is dictated by the height of an associated ImageList, if any, followed by the height of the assigned Font.

**Update**: turns out that [`LVM_SETITEMHEIGHT`](http://www.minigui.org/api_ref/3.0.12_threads/group__mgext__ctrl__listview__msgs.html#gaa7bcd7c74de45e062100ee25d8e21980) is part of the [MiniGUI library](http://www.minigui.org), not part of the Win32 API.  In that case, you would have to use the `LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` window style and then subclass the ListView to handle the [`WM_MEASUREITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775925.aspx) message.

Comment: There is no `LVM_SETITEMHEIGHT` message.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I use `CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"" ,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_BORDER | LVS_OWNDERDRAWFIXED  , 10, 10, 300, 190, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0); ` but i get this error `error C2065: 'LVS_OWNDERDRAWFIXED' : undeclared identifier`.Please what's wrong?

Comment: @Zahra19977 do you have `#include <CommCtrl.h>` in your code?

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau  Thanks for response..Yes i have included the header..I googled but didnt find `LVS_OWNDERDRAWFIXED` in the documentation.

Comment: @Zahra19977 it is `LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`, not `LVS_OWNDERDRAWFIXED`